# ckeditor how to put <br> after image upload

Tags: javascript, image, upload, ckeditor

I have searched for this answer and I thought I've found it.
Someone suggested this one.

```
editor.on('instanceReady', function() {
    editor.widgets.registered.uploadimage.onUploaded = function(upload) {
        this.replaceWith('<img src="' + upload.url + '"><br>br>');
    }
});
```

But my question is where should I put this function?

should it go to **config.js** like

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function(config) {
    //...
};
editor.on('instanceReady', function() {
    editor.widgets.registered.uploadimage.onUploaded = function(upload) {
        this.replaceWith('<img src="' + upload.url + '"><br>br>');
    }
});
// ----------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

I had to do this in the html.

```
<script>
editor = CKEDITOR.replace('contents');
editor.on('instanceReady', function() {
    editor.widgets.registered.uploadimage.onUploaded = function(upload) {
        this.replaceWith('<img src="' + upload.url + '"><br><br>');
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: onUploaded method is not called, do you have any idea about this ?